# AngularJS Google Map (ng-map) icon url not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

For some reason my markers are not showing when i use an absolute url instead of a relative one.

In my view i use:

```
<marker ... icon="{url: '{{markerSrc}}'}"></marker>
```

When i do this (in my controller):

```
$scope.markerSrc = "/images/marker.png";
```

everything works and the icon is shown

but when i do:

```
$scope.markerSrc = "http://complete/path/to/marker/images/marker.png";
```

i get an error:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/%7Burl:%20'http://complete/path/to/marker/images/marker.png'%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

i tried different methods like

```
<marker ... icon="{url: "'{{markerSrc}}'" }"></marker>
<marker ... icon="{url: "{{markerSrc}}" }"></marker>
<marker ... icon="{url: {{markerSrc}} }"></marker>
```

but none seem to work...

Comment: Strange, it's actually putting `{url:` as part of the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `marker` directive `icon` attribute  syntax from:

```
<marker ... icon="{url: '{{markerSrc}}'}"></marker>
```

to

```
<marker ... icon="{{markerSrc}}"></marker>
```

**Example**

```js
var app = angular.module('appMaps', ['ngMap']);
app.controller('mapCtrl', function ($scope) {
    

    $scope.cities = [
       { id: 1, name : "Brisbane", location: [-33.867396, 151.206854] },
        { id: 2, name: "Sydney", location: [-27.46758, 153.027892] },
        { id: 3, name: "Perth", location: [-31.953159, 115.849915] }
    ];


    $scope.markerSrc = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png";

});
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
<div ng-app="appMaps" ng-controller="mapCtrl">
        <map center="[-24.667856, 133.630694]" zoom="4">
            <marker id='ID{{city.id}}' ng-repeat="city in cities" position="{{city.location}}" icon="{{markerSrc}}"   >
            </marker>
            
        </map>
</div>
```